# How to align an icon with a title but not the paragraph?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

At the request of my teacher, I have to reproduce this table ***with bootstrap and grid*** but I do not understand how to align the icon with the titles ***while keeping the paragraph vertically aligned with the title.***

[image]

I tried in flex but I don't manage to have a good alignment.

I also tried with a list and changed the list-style but the icon is not aligned...

So I try in absolute position but it seems complicated for nothing ...

```css
#gout article {
  width: 300px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

#gout #art-naturel::before {
  content: url(../img/organic-2.png);
  position: absolute;
  left: -60px;
  top: -20px;
}

#gout #art-bio::before {
  content: url(../img/organic-1.png);
  position: absolute;
  left: -60px;
  top: -20px;
}

#gout #art-encas::before {
  content: url(../img/grain-1.png);
  position: absolute;
  left: -60px;
  top: -20px;
}

#gout #art-calorie::before {
  content: url(../img/organic-1.png);
  position: absolute;
  left: -60px;
  top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<section id="gout" class="container">

  <!-- LIGNE 1  -->
  <div class="row">
    <section class="col-12 d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-around">
      <article>
        <h3>Du naturel <br> au goûter ?</h3>
      </article>
      <article id="art-naturel">
        <h4>Du naturel</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores ipsum saepe soluta rerum ipsa.</p>
      </article>

      <article id="art-bio">
        <h4>Exploitation bio</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores ipsum saepe soluta rerum ipsa.</p>
      </article>
  </div>


  <!-- LIGNE 2  -->
  <div class="row">
    <section class="col-12 d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-around">
      <article> </article>
      <article id="art-encas">
        <h4>Encas</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores ipsum saepe soluta rerum ipsa.</p>
      </article>

      <article id="art-calorie">
        <h4>Calories</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores ipsum saepe soluta rerum ipsa.</p>
      </article>
  </div>
  </section>
```

can you explain to me what is the best method to align an icon to a text in a clean way?

In this context, what confuses me is the paragraphs ...

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is how you wanted to have the elements aligned.

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <article>
        <img class="pl-5 pt-5" src="https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQHH3QDd1WaMVA/company-logo_200_200/0?e=2159024400&v=beta&t=EqNLQ1MfX-edLauEkAsFP2evAuCvDzrfg0qmTAAhYQ4"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 pt-5">
        <h3>Du naturel <br> au goûter ?</h3>
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <article id="art-naturel">
            <h4>Du naturel</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores ipsum saepe soluta rerum ipsa.</p>
          </article>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <article id="art-bio">
            <h4>Exploitation bio</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores ipsum saepe soluta rerum ipsa.</p>
          </article>
          
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <article id="art-encas">
            <h4>Encas</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores ipsum saepe soluta rerum ipsa.</p>
          </article>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <article id="art-calorie">
            <h4>Calories</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores ipsum saepe soluta rerum ipsa.</p>
          </article>
        </div>
          
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have added the icon in the HTML and not the CSS, for easy alignment. I have commented on the image in the CSS.

I have not changed anything in the CSS.

```
    #gout article {
      width: 300px;
      margin-right: 20px;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    #gout #art-naturel::before {
      //content: url(../img/organic-2.png);
      position: absolute;
      left: -60px;
      top: -20px;
    }
    
    #gout #art-bio::before {
      //content: url(../img/organic-1.png);
      position: absolute;
      left: -60px;
      top: -20px;
    }
    
    #gout #art-encas::before {
      //content: url(../img/grain-1.png);
      position: absolute;
      left: -60px;
      top: -20px;
    }
    
    #gout #art-calorie::before {
      content: url(../img/organic-1.png);
      position: absolute;
      left: -60px;
      top: -20px;
    }
```